# Google Distance Matrix API Vectorization

Tags: javascript, google-api

So, I'm trying to find the travel time of several segments of road using the Distance Matrix (DM) API. There are 2 inputs for the DM API: origins and destinations. When I input all my origins and all of my destinations, the DM API makes the following call:

service.getDistanceMatrix(request).then((response) => ...

and it returns a matrix of the travel time and distance from every origin to every destination. That makes sense, that's what it's supposed to do. But I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to have it only return the travel time for the particular road segments I'm interested in? For example, only give me the travel time for the element with index 0 in origins traveling to the element with index 0 in destinations. Something along the lines of a "getDistanceVector" instead of a getDistanceMatrix. Every origin only returns a single value instead of an array of values with length equal to the destinations array. I considered just doing each call with 1 origin and 1 destination and looping the calls, but I wasn't sure if that would make me hit my daily limit too fast. If you know the answer to that, that would also be sufficient. I don't mind writing a code to sift through all the values, but the computation time might get annoying if I increase the number of points so if anyone knows an answer I would greatly appreciate any help, or if you know I'm using the wrong API that would also be very good to know. Thanks

I tried looking at the google documentation for other methods, but didn't see anything out of the box that fit what I was looking for. I'll go back and continue looking in case I missed something, but it's my first time reading through this sort of thing. I did find the function "callback" :

```
function callback(response, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        var element = results[j];
        var distance = element.distance.text;
        var duration = element.duration.text;
        var from = origins[i];
        var to = destinations[j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I could change this to just remove the inner for loop, I think I'd be okay. But I'm not sure where I would do that. Again, baby's first time using an API.

Comment: Check [the billing page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing) - it says you get charged for originCount * destinationCount when you use distance matrix, so you'd be better off looping over single queries.